# ManagedObject removed from NSArrayController not deleted.

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a lot of dangling ManagedObjects and wonder why.

It might have something to with the inverse relationships. Are Core data inverse relationships created automagically -- during the initial Add process. Not the final Remove.

I see the generated 'mutator' methods in the `NSManagedObject`

```
- (void)addChildObject:(Child *)value
```

- Is this the place for those magic inverse sets *

Nevertheless, almost all Objects remain after a delete. And i use Cascade!
In another similar matter, Deny doesn't prevent deletions as suggested.

To be clear there are no `NSOrderedSet` in use. Just standard `NSSets`.

UPDATE: Probably not a Inverse relationship issue. It seems that objects removed from immediate NSArrayControllers are deleted -- but not objects removed from `NSArrayControllers` connected via `Content Set` or `Content Object`. Ie. Only those with the `managedObjectContext` set to Files Owner...

Answer (score 3):

YES. The lil' print.

> removeObject: Removes object from the receiver’s content collection.
>
> - (void)removeObject:(id)object
>
> If you are using Core Data, the exact semantics of this method differ
>   depending on the settings for the array controller. If the receiver’s
>   content is fetched automatically, removed objects are marked for
>   deletion by the managed object context (and hence removal from the
>   object graph). **If, however, the receiver’s contentSet is bound to a
>   relationship, removeObject: by default only removes the object from
>   the relationship (not from the object graph).** You can, though, set the
>   “Deletes Object on Remove” option for the contentSet binding, in which
>   case objects are marked for deletion as well as being removed from the
>   relationship.